# Different results using CLT and t.test() in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble on an assignment involving t-tests, in which i'm asked to calculate a p-value 10000 times from a sample n=5 of a population and describe the proportion of times in which it is below 0.05.
Here's the source file

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/babies.txt"
filename <- basename(url)
download(url, destfile=filename)
babies <- read.table("babies.txt", header=TRUE)
bwt.nonsmoke <- filter(babies, smoke==0) %>% select(bwt) %>% unlist 
bwt.smoke <- filter(babies, smoke==1) %>% select(bwt) %>% unlist
```

I tried to use the following approach to the problem and can't understand why it doesn't work.

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 5
alpha <- 0.05
B <- 10000

reject <- function(N, alpha= 0.05){
a <- (sample(bwt.nonsmoke, N))
b <- (sample(bwt.smoke, N))
diff <- mean(a)-mean(b)
se <- sqrt(var(a)/length(a) + var(b)/length(b))
tstat <- diff/se
righttail <- 1 - pnorm(abs(tstat))
lefttail <- pnorm(-abs(tstat))
pval <- lefttail + righttail
pval < alpha
}
rejections <- replicate(B, reject(N))
mean(rejections)
```

which returns a value of `0.1725`

However, when using this code instead

```
B <- 10000
alpha <- 0.05
N <- 5
set.seed(1)
reject <- function(N, alpha=0.05){
    dat.ns <- sample(bwt.nonsmoke, N)
    dat.s <- sample(bwt.smoke, N)
    pval <- t.test(dat.s, dat.ns)$p.value
    pval < alpha
}
rejections <- replicate(B, reject(N))
mean(rejections)
```

I get the correct answer, which is `0.096`.

Can anyone shed some light on this one?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you need to use `pt()` rather than `pnorm()`, with appropriate degrees of freedom.

```
set.seed(1)
reject <- function(N, alpha = 0.05) {
    a <- (sample(bwt.nonsmoke, N))
    b <- (sample(bwt.smoke, N))
    n1 <- length(a)
    n2 <- length(b)
    var1 <- var(a)
    var2 <- var(b)
    diff <- mean(a) - mean(b)
    tmp <- var1/n1 + var2/n2
    se <- sqrt(tmp)
    df <- tmp^2 / ( ( ((var1/n1)^2)/(n1-1) ) + ( ((var2/n2)^2)/(n2-1) ) )
    tstat <- diff/se
    pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
    pval < alpha
}
rejections <- replicate(B, reject(N))
mean(rejections)
# [1] 0.096
```

### Additional details

In the comments you (rightly) ask for some details and explanation.

First is the issue of why `pt()` rather than `pnorm()`. The answer is because you're doing a t-test of the difference in means; we use the t distribution rather than the normal distribution in particular in small samples.

Next is the question of how the t-test works and how to do the calculation. I think the [Investopedia page on t-tests](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/t-test.asp) is very accessible and easily explains this issue.

We need degrees of freedom because that's how the t distribution is parameterized. That resource gives the correct equation for degrees of freedom with unequal variance as:

[image]

The

Comment: It did work, although I don't fully understand as to why is that. The textbook I'm reading does not mention pt() or degress of freedom. Would you mind elaborating on that a little bit?

Comment: @dairelix Done!

Comment: Thank you so much! You're freaking awesome! It became so much clearer now!
Over the last few lines, you wrote
```
pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
```
to calculate the p-value just by doubling the value under the left-tail, is that right?

Comment: @dairelix Yeah; since it's a symmetric distribution, it will be equivalent to the left tail plus the right tail

Comment: The link you provided states that when the number of samples in each group is the same, or the variance of the two data sets is similar, one should use the Equal Variance T-test.
However I see you used the degrees of freedom of a Unequal Variance T-test. Why is that, since both samples have the same number?